# staticwebapp.config.json not redirecting on Azure static website

Tags: azure, web, static, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to get sub urls working on a SPA located on an azure static website

I have placed a staticwebapp.config.json in my root for the app, it can be viewed here: https://www.fplgameweek.com/staticwebapp.config.json

File is looking like this:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "serve": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  ],
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html",
    "exclude": [
      "/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}",
      "/css/*"
    ]
  },
  "responseOverrides": {
    "404": {
      "rewrite": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I go to an unknown url, like https://www.fplgameweek.com/unknown I expect to be redirected to my main page, but I'm not. I get a 404 error saying the requested content does not exist.

Why am I not redirected to my index.html from unknown url's?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#define-routes), either `rewrite` or `redirect` should be used to specify target location in staticwebapp.config.json file.

`serve` is part of the now deprecated [routes.json](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/wiki/routes.json-reference-(deprecated)) approach.